# i try to run django project inside google cloud VM instance and i am receiving error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

my project is working locally fine but when i clone my project from git **inside google cloud  VM** and try to run the project without any database configuration also i am receiving

error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2' and it is comming from pandas
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/bz2.py", line 19, in 
**from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor**
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
can any one tell me the solution for it

Comment: There are several possibilities for this error. Edit your question with details on the OS and how you installed and set up your application. Also, Google search for this error so that you understand what information we need to answer your question.

Comment: @Veera Could you please let me know the status of your issue. If resolved; please post the answer so, that it will be helpful for the other community members.